# Why istringstream appends '-1' character at the end of stream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stream, char, istringstream

I've noticed that when I'm using istringstream eof() doesn't return true even if the whole string is "consumed". For example:

```
char ch;
istringstream ss{ "0" };
ss >> ch;
cout << ss.peek() << " " << (ss.eof() ? "true" : "false");
```

Outputs(VS2015):

```
-1 false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eof()` isn't supposed to return `true` when all the data is consumed. It's supposed to return `true` when you attempt to read *more* data than is available.

In this example, you never do that.

In particular, `peek` is a "request", that won't set EOF even when there's nothing left to read; because you're, well, peeking. However, it *will* return the value of the macro `EOF` (commonly -1), which is what you're seeing when you output `peek()`'s result. Nothing is "appended" to the stream.

Read the documentation for functions that you use.

Comment: Technically that effect could be depending on  platform, -1 is not actually code of EOF - code of EOF is 26, but code of  "End of Transmission" - 255. Some  protocols used it actively, e.g. FTP uses it (making impossible to transfer or create a file with Russian letter я in it - because in extended ASCII  that letter got code 255 - a problem very obvious with Windows XP  FTP)

Comment: @Swift: The C macro `EOF` is distinct from the ASCII control code `EOF`. You're right that it's implementation-defined and may not be -1, though it basically always is (because no other negative value has purpose, and no positive value or 0 makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::istream::peek
```

> Peek next character Returns the next character in the input sequence,
>   without extracting it: The character is left as the next character to
>   be extracted from the stream.
>
> If any internal state flags is already set before the call or is set
>   during the call, the function returns the end-of-file value (EOF).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/